# Two not so useful answers given by the same user

Tags: discussion

I have this question [Ordering with relation column sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426763/ordering-with-relation-column-sum). And it has three answers. Two answers given by the same user. And the answer is not useful. Normally people don't view the question at all if it has three answers. They think the OP may already have the answer. So, now the question therefore is not getting enough attention. And what about those two absolutely nothing answers by the same user. I do not have enough reputation to downvote the answer. But, then again. Even If I have enough reputation why would anybody lose their 1 reputation to downvote such answer?

Comment: The duplicate answers appear to have been a mistake. It seems one was intended as an edit of the other. I deleted the older one.

Comment: Incorrect answers invariably *encourage* an SO user to post a better answer.  https://xkcd.com/386/

Answer (score 2):

Let's address the duplicate answer bit.  Long story sort, I'd blame either lag or a maintenance period in which answers couldn't be submitted, although neither can be demonstrated.

What you can do in this scenario is, ironically, what you just did; higher rep users who watch Meta can help correct this issue.

As to...

> Normally people don't view the question at all if it has three answers.  They think the OP may already have the answer.

No, that's not the case.  At least, I hope it isn't.

> Even if I have enough reputation why would anybody looe their 1 reputation to downvote such answer?

To help us rank useful answers.  Useful answers are upvoted; not so useful answers are downvoted.  It also factors *heavily* into the answer ban, and so it isn't something to be done lightly.